# Global login to password protected pages

Tags: login, password

I'm using WP's password protection to hide certain pages so only visitors that received a password can access them. But I don't want other visitors to see the protected pages in the navigation. Only when they entered the correct password they shall see the "exclusive" pages and get access to them. That requires me to have a global input-field (ideally in the navigation-area) where they can enter the password and will then be taken to the first password protected page as well as see the protected page now in the navigation.

As far as I understood this is basically the same topic but unfortunately there's no answer to it yet: [Login using the password from protected pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6072/login-using-the-password-from-protected-pages)

I **don't** want to use the regular Wordpress Login function since I don't want/need to have individual users. Just one password to rule them all.

I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: It may be easier to just create a single subscriber and have everyone log in as that one user. You can still use a custom form that only requires password, and log them in via `wp_singon`. I think all the other things you want to do will be much easier, there are plugins that can show content and menu items based on the logged-in user's role.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Milo!
So far having only a single subscriber is what I came up with as well. This might already be sufficient. I got the hiding of content and menu-items working with a plug-in now. Still working on the custom login though. I couldn't figure a proper way how to log-in this user using only the password in the form. Since I'm not very experienced in PHP, how exactly does `wp_signon` work and how would I use it to create the custom login??